# Catching all exceptions inside server api - js

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I'm trying to figure out a way to catch all exceptions inside server api call and send it to the client side.

One simple method I followed was using try,catch.

api.js

```
server.get('/api/test/', passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', {
session: false
}), (req, res, next) => { 

try{
   //Code here - catches error

 MongoClient.connect(MongodbConnectionString, {
  useNewUrlParser: true
   }, function(err, client) {

  //Code here - **Doesn't catch errors**

   var t = db.collection('testdb').find({
      "ID": "1"          
  });

  t.count(function(err, count) {

  //Code here - **Doesn't catch errors**

  });
  });

}catch(error){
    return res.send({
            "message": ""+error+""
        });
}



});
```

Errors inside callback function is not handled. Is this the correct way of doing it? Can anything could be done with promises?Help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Essentially, all callback functions are `async` functions hence a `try/catch` will not be able to catch the inner execution. AFAIK, you will have to individually catch and throw the error in each callback function.

Comment: Is there any other to handle such errors ?

Comment: Is this in node.js?

Comment: yes..it is in nodejs